# How Can I Read a lot of Colums as a Data in a File and Store Them in a Array Correctly in Perl

Tags: perl

Right now I am trying to do some comparison with using some datas that are belongs to two different input files.

The first input file looks like this: I have two rows and a lot of columns.

```
id    date1       time1       date2       time2      ne  CC0 CC1   CC2  CC3  CC4... due to CC127 

1    2016-09-26  14:13:56   2016-09-26  14:08:56    S1   7   1226   0   86    0 
2    2016-09-26  14:13:56   2016-09-26  14:08:56    S2   8   1346   2   97   12
```

Second input file looks like this:

```
ne  type  time threshold

S1  CC000  09   50

S1  CC000  10   50

S1  CC000  11   50

S1  CC000  12   50

S1  CC000  13   50

S1  CC000  14   50
```

My main aim is to read those two files, storing necessary informations and datas in the arrays. If the time(as an hour) and ne condition matches then ı want to compare its data and its threshold value. If data is bigger than the threshold, ı want to keep this data and write them another file as a result. For example, for ne S1, and hour 14, CC0 data is equal to 7 and threshold is equal to 50.

So far ı wrote this codes; ( the last edited one, with help of Chris)

```
    #! /usr/bin/perl -w

#compiler profilleri
use strict;
use warnings;

#dosya locationları

my $input_file="C:/Perl64/output/innput.txt";
my $s1_threshold="C:/Perl64/output/s1_threshold.txt";

#komutlar######


my $date; my $time; my $ne; my @hour; my @cc;
my $i=0; my $j=0;

    open INPUT, "< $input_file" or die "$0: open of $input_file failed, error: $! \n";

    while ( defined ($_=<INPUT>) )
    {   

        my $line1 = $_;
        my ( undef, $date, $time, undef, undef, $ne, @cc) = split (' ',$line1);
        #print("$cc[16]\n");

        my @time1= split(':',$time);
        @hour=split(',',$time1[0]);

        #print("@hour\n");

    open THR, "< $s1_threshold" or die "$0: open pf $s1_threshold failed, error: $! \n";
    while (defined($_=<THR>) )
    {
        my $line2=$_;
        my ($ne1, $cc_type, $time1, $threshold ) =split(' ',$line2);

        if( $hour[0] == $time1 && $ne eq $ne1 )
        {
            for ( $i=0;$i<128;$i++)
            {
               if ( $cc[$i] > $threshold )
               {
                  # print("$cc[$i]\n");
               }
             }
        }
    }
  }
```

Now ı can obtain all data correctly in a simple way, but when it comes to final if command I mean this,

```
if ( $      cc[$i] > $threshold )
```

cc array values are being compared with all of the threshold values, not just the value for related cc_type and hour.
Second input file contains threshold values with respond to cc_types. For each cc_type there are 23 different value with respect to hour so ı want to compare only for that specific hour and cc_type. How can ı fix that?

(When ı figure out the first part for that, ı will add the same procedure by adding another threshold file for S2. )

ı am a newbie in perl language, so any kind answer related to this appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** Changed the compare line to `if ( $hour1 == $hour2 && $ne1 eq $ne2 )` and moved `my $i = ...` inside the `if` statement.

If I understand the 'type' variable correctly, (`CC000` => `000`), then the changed code here might do what you need.

Instead of using `substr` to get the data, I`split` the fields into the variables.

In the first file, the last receiver, `@cc`, gets all the remaining columns in the input line, (you stated there is only one line of data in the first file).

If there is only 1 line, there is no need for a `while` loop to read the data. Simply, note how I read the 1 line into the variables, (`split ' ', <$fh>`).

Since you don't seem to need `date1` and `time1`, I assigned them to `undef`. (`undef` here is just a placeholder for values you don't want to capture. I could have also used `undef` for the first field, but I assigned it to `$id` which you aren't using anyway).

Also, I used lexical filehandles, (`$fh`, `$fh2`), instead of `INPUT` and `THR`, because it is the preferred practice. I can't say exactly why it is preferred, but I think it was adopted in perl v 5.6.

I also used the [3 argument](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl56delta.html#open()-with-more-than-two-arguments), (filehandle, mode, file) mode of opening a file. (You used the 2 argument, the 3 arg. was introduced in perl ver. 5.6. It is a safer form of `open`).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input_file = 'file1';
my $s1_threshold="file2";

open my $fh, '<', $input_file
    or die "$0: open of $input_file failed, error: $! \n";

my ($id, $date, $time1, undef, undef, $ne1, @cc) = split ' ', <$fh>;

close $fh or die "$0: close of $input_file failed, error: $! \n";

# get hour from time1
my $hour1 = substr $time1, 0, 2;

open my $fh2, '<', $s1_threshold
    or die "$0: open pf $s1_threshold failed, error: $! \n";

while (<$fh2>) {
    my ($ne2, $cc, $hour2, $threshold) = split;

    if ( $hour1 == $hour2 && $ne1 eq $ne2 ) {
        my $i = 0 + substr $cc, 2;

        if ( $cc[$i] > $threshold )
        {
            print("$cc[$i]\n");
            print ("match\n");
         }
         else
         {
            print("not match\n");
         }
    }
}
close $fh2 or die "$0: close pf $s1_threshold failed, error: $! \n";
```

Comment: thanks for the kind answer, ı removed substr commands and added split command to obtain all data ı need. Right now, ı can retrieve all data correctly but still if else commands dont work correctly ı didnt understand why?

Comment: @evenstar Your code looks like its doing many unnecessary steps - especially assigning to `my @cc116=split(',',$satir[122]); my @cc117=split(',',$satir[123]); `, `etc`. But to answer your question about `if .. else`, the line `if( @hour == @time1)` should work with `if( $hour[0] == $time1[0])`

Comment: Now it works correctly, Can you please explain why we are using like that, why array element [0]?. By the way I couldnt edit all the input files but in the first file, ı have 2 rows and 136 columns, it is not only one line. In the second file ı have 4 columns and a lot of rows. I couldnt figure out how can ı obtain 127 columns data separetely in a simple way, thats why ı manuelly assigned split commands.

Comment: So there are 2 rows in the first file. Are both rows data or is the first row a header and the second row data?

Comment: Both of them contains data, but first row data is for ne S1, and the second row data is for S2.. I am trying to take baby steps so ı didnt add any code related to S2 data and its threshold file. When ı fully understand the first part, ı will add for s2 too and will write related result in another file.. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @evenstar I made 1 change to my answer, (see **Update**). To get `$i`, instead of using a loop as you've done, (` for ( $i=0;$i<128;$i++)`), get `$i` as I did in my code, (` my $i = 0 + substr $cc, 2;
`).

Comment: Thank you so much Chris, ı can able to finish my code and store it as a txt file backup. Regards.

Comment: @evenstar Glad I was a help in completing your code. (I did work out a program that reads both lines from file 1 if you want to see it).

Comment: right now my code constitute of three different files. Once I understood the method, ı was able to write the remaining ones thanks to your help :). As an output, ı write all necessary informations in a single output backup file. For further, ı wanna learn how to email this without using any module.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use all of the values as one single integer, which will never work. You need to get those values one by one. Also the way you are parsing the lines is calling for trouble. You are better of with something like this:

```
my ($id, $date1, $time1, $date2, $time2, $ne, $cc0, $cc1, $cc2, $cc3, $cc4) = split /\s+/, $sonuc;
```

Now you can use `$cc0, $cc1, ...` individually as integers.

Comment: When ı try to use like this, all the data which ı want to read from separately are parsed only in $id variable and the other variables like $date1... contains no data, so it doesnt work.

Comment: That's because I simplified the case to space separated fields, but in your file above you might have more than one space or tabs between fields. I've edited the answer to account for that, hope that helps.